# php - xml validation against xsd

Tags: php, xml, validation, xsd

When I validate my xml file against xsd with several validation tools, they all gives back positive result: validation successful.

But when do that in php with schemaValidate, validation breaks exactly after 60 seconds showing blank page. I'm trying to find some explanation for this:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();

$doc->load('C:\a\xml.xml');


try{

    $is_valid_xml = $doc->schemaValidate('http://xxxxxxx/schema.xsd');

    if ($is_valid_xml == true) {
        echo 'ok';
        }else {
        throw new Exception('Validation not successful!');
    }

    }catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "<br />"; 

    } finally {
    print_r(error_get_last());
}
```

When I use the above method on some other generic xml+xsd example it works fine. If I mess up that xml deliberately I get the result "Caught exception: Validation not succesfull!" and some error info, but with my real xml+xsd files (which are far more complicated) I get blank page.

Any idea why is that happening? This exact 60 sec seems like some session time out or something like that but I have looked in php.ini it is set to 1440 sec (session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440)...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  There is good advice on asking effective questions in the [SO help files](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and in Eric Raymond and Rick Moen's essay [How to ask questions the smart way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html).  You'll get better responses if you provide a [minimal complete verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In cutting your real XML and XSD down to the smallest example that exhibits the problem behavior, you may discover the problem and no longer need to ask the question -- that's just a risk you have to take.

Comment: Hi tnx for instructions. I found the solution. The problem was in php.ini >>> max_execution_time = 30

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. The problem was in php.ini >>> max_execution_time = 30